# Worklight preview shows Network Error - 404

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-studio

I am getting the following error in firebug when I preview my app from Worklight console. Also the image is missing in preview.

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://192.168.3.100:10080/WorklightSample/apps/services/preview/MyApp/common/0/images/logo.png"
```

All the files are present in the corresponnding folders in the project. From the tips got from Stackoverflow and other forums, I tried the following:

1. Cleared wlBuildResources
2. Cleaned Worklight Development Server
3. Cleared bin folder
4. Deleted Worklight Development Server and restarted eclipse
5. Changed workspace

All these of no use. How can I remove this error?

Edit:
My index.html is:

```
<body style="display:none;">
        <div data-role="page" id="loginPageDiv">
            <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="forgotPasswordPageDiv">
            <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px"></div>
        </div>
<script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#loginPageDiv").load("pages/loginPage.html");
        });
        </script>
    </body>
```

and my loginPage.html in pages folder is

```
<div id="wrapper">
<img src="../images/logo.png" /> <br>
<div id="searchText">Please enter your username and password</div>
<input id="emailBox" class="loginInput" type="text" placeholder="Email Address">
<input id="passwordBox"  class="loginInput" type="text" placeholder="Password"><br> 
<div id="checkboxDiv"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked">Keep me signed in</div> <br>
<input type="submit" class="btn-common-green" name="searchBtn" value="Search" onclick="getSearchResults();">
</div>
```

When i add the code as

```
<img src="images/logo.png" />
```

in index.html, the image is being loaded in index page. Why it is not taking the image when code is given in inner page?

Comment: Provide the project where we could see this happening, reproduce it and try to debug. Also mention your Worklight version and build number. And on which browser you are seeing this phenomena.

Comment: I cannot give you my project due to security reasons. My worklight version is 6.2. Browser is Mozilla firefox 33

Comment: Because I see this question a sa low quality question, given that you are not providing anything that can help you debug it. If the application is sensitive and you need help - consider removing this question from Stack Overflow and open a PMR (support ticket) for IBM to be able to provide you support. If you can recreate it with a NEW app as well, provide that.

Comment: i have edited questions and added details. please check. is because image is added in an inner page server is not loading it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I do not believe you need the follow code snippet where you've placed it. Rather, you need to call that page in `main.js > wlCommonInit()`.
2. For the `img` tag, it should work without the `..`: `<img src="images/logo.png" />`